# The server is not accessible only from my IP?

Tags: centos, apache-httpd

I am Using a CentOS 7 and Apache 2.4 as my website host. I tried a number of other machine and some can reach the server and some cannot including my PC. I have disabled stopped firewall (`systemctl stop firewalld.service` and even `service iptables stop`) and turned off selinux (`setenforce 0`). Yet, it's not possible to reach the website and http request will be timeout. What is wrong with it?

```
>> netstat -tunalp | grep :80
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      9480/httpd          
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:802           0.0.0.0:*                           1897/rpc.statd
```

and  Apache `Listen` directive is set to `Listen 80`

I cannot even ping the sever from my own PC (which has a public IP). Which part of CentOS may hinder my connection?

Comment: Are you able to access the website from your own system(i.e CentOS 7 machine itself)? If yes, check your IP. Then check the IP of the machine from where you are trying to access your website. Are both machines in the same subnet ? Also give me the output of *telnet <ip> 80* from the machine you are trying to access the website

Comment: Yes, The site is accessible locally (CentOS's firefox). I try to connect the server from Internet in another sity so they are not on the same subnet. Here is the output of telnet: `Connecting To {ip}...Could not open connection to the host, on port 80: Connect failed`

Comment: ok .. so is the Centos 7 inside a vm or its the host machine itself ? are you sure you are accessing the website from another city via public ip ? you shud do proper port forwarding if you Centos 7 box is having a private ip

Comment: @OsChannelDotCom CentOS is hosted by VMware. I am trying to access it from another city. but i cannot. How should I do that (prot forwarding)?

Comment: Do you know if there's like other software using the same port? I don't know something like `haproxy`

Comment: stop NetworkManager service.

Also, try to connect to it via telnet
telnet <ip address> 80
telnet localhost 80

Answer (score 3):

```
>> netstat -tunalp | grep :80  
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      9480/httpd
```

Did you intend to only listen for ipv6 connections? (see that the line starts with tcp6?)  If you want it to only bind to the ipv4 address, try using `Listen 0.0.0.0:80` instead.

Comment: No, I need ipv4 only.

Comment: Well, according to your output, you're only listening on the ipv6 address.  Try changing your `Listen`.

Comment: Did apache httpd successfully restart after you made the change?  Also, are you sure your system has an IPv4 address?

Comment: I suggest looking to see what port the `httpd` process is listening on.  Instead of grepping for :80, grep for httpd.

Comment: why don't you use 'Listen 80' in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf ?

Comment: @zhangjie I tested that as well without success.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have some network issue. You can run this command `netstat -tunalp | grep :80` as root user and check http is LISTING on which IP address. Also Check your apache configuration for `Listen` directive.

Comment: It should be revised service status httpd by `systemctl status httpd`

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing two problems with your configuration as you've described it.

1. You say you disabled the firewall then mention the command `systemctl start firewalld.service`.  This command will START the firewall.  Use `systemctl stop firewalld.service` to stop it.
2. You mention that you're unable to access the server from your PC and that your PC has a public IP.  Are you using IPv4 or IPv6?  If the latter then there's no problem here provided that both machines are using 'real' addresses and not link-local (fe80::) addresses.  But if you are attempting to use IPv4 network you're going to want to make sure that you server is using a public address or is properly NAT'ed.

Comment: server _is_ accessible over SSH, so addressing is not likely the issue.  the problem is apparently specific to http.

Comment: "Now, I cannot even ping the sever from my own PC (which has a public IP)." - OP  I don't see how he can ssh if he can't ping unless he has a firewall rule to explicitly block ICMP

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I used `systemctl stop firewalld.service` (I corrected the question). My machine and server both have public ipv4 ips. How can server be NATed properly? (The host machine is not managed by me and I have root access to the hosted os (CentOS) only)

Comment: "make sure that you server is using a public address or is properly NAT'ed"  If the server is using a public address then it shouldn't need to be NAT'ed.  If you're using IPv4, then your problem is the apache configuration.  It's listening on IPv6, but not IPv4.

Answer (score 0):

If you set up CentOS yourself, you should know whether you've blocked specific remote IPs in `firewalld` or `iptables`.  IOW I doubt that's the problem.  Similarly there shouldn't be an issue with SELinux discriminating against specific remote IPs.  And the same logic applies to Apache...  I'm not convinced CentOS is the problem.

Can you try and confirm which network hop is blocking HTTP but allowing SSH?

E.g. Google let me view their website, but they block SSH at the border of their internal network.  I can see this with TCP traceroute available on any decent Linux install.

```
# traceroute -T google.com    # port 80 is the default
traceroute to google.com (216.58.210.78), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  gateway (172.16.9.1)  3.070 ms  3.048 ms  3.024 ms
 2  host-89-243-96-1.as13285.net (89.243.96.1)  17.659 ms  17.664 ms  21.510 ms
 3  xe-11-2-0-bragg001.bre.as13285.net (78.151.225.39)  21.524 ms  21.643 ms  25.172 ms
 4  host-78-151-225-88.static.as13285.net (78.151.225.88)  25.170 ms  27.548 ms host-78-151-229-28.as13285.net (78.151.229.28)  27.538 ms
 5  host-78-144-8-63.as13285.net (78.144.8.63)  34.949 ms host-78-144-12-227.as13285.net (78.144.12.227)  37.634 ms host-78-144-10-17.as13285.net (78.144.10.17)  37.581 ms
 6  72.14.214.222 (72.14.214.222)  37.591 ms  32.854 ms  32.763 ms
 7  216.239.54.159 (216.239.54.159)  35.622 ms 72.14.237.253 (72.14.237.253)  23.919 ms  23.775 ms
 8  72.14.238.185 (72.14.238.185)  26.728 ms  23.559 ms  23.496 ms
 9  lhr14s24-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.210.78)  26.608 ms  22.107 ms  24.961 ms

# traceroute -T google.com -p 22    # port 22 for SSH
traceroute to google.com (216.58.198.206), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  gateway (172.16.9.1)  3.020 ms  2.977 ms  2.960 ms
 2  host-89-243-96-1.as13285.net (89.243.96.1)  16.724 ms  16.728 ms  16.713 ms
 3  xe-11-2-0-bragg001.bre.as13285.net (78.151.225.39)  22.195 ms  22.205 ms  24.498 ms
 4  host-78-151-225-18.static.as13285.net (78.151.225.18)  24.507 ms host-78-151-225-116.static.as13285.net (78.151.225.116)  24.552 ms  27.647 ms
 5  host-78-144-10-21.as13285.net (78.144.10.21)  34.491 ms host-78-144-12-117.as13285.net (78.144.12.117)  34.474 ms host-78-144-10-235.as13285.net (78.144.10.235)  34.463 ms
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
```

Note this assumes ICMP "TTL exceeded" errors are not being blocked somewhere.  Still, traceroute is always great fun when it works :).